# Spring boot custom Servlet doesn't map to bean name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I am trying to register a custom servlet.

I used this code in a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean (name="probe")
public PingServlet probe(){
    return new PingServlet();
}
```

I thought this would be mapped to /probe, but it doesn't. I maps to '/' and the reason is that in class `ServletContextInitializerBeans`, there this method:

```
private <T, B extends T> void addAsRegistrationBean(ListableBeanFactory beanFactory,
        Class<T> type, Class<B> beanType, RegistrationBeanAdapter<T> adapter) {
    List<Map.Entry<String, B>> beans = getOrderedBeansOfType(beanFactory, beanType,
            this.seen);
    for (Entry<String, B> bean : beans) {
        if (this.seen.add(bean.getValue())) {
            int order = getOrder(bean.getValue());
            String beanName = bean.getKey();
            // One that we haven't already seen
            RegistrationBean registration = adapter.createRegistrationBean(beanName,
                    bean.getValue(), beans.size());
            registration.setName(beanName);
            registration.setOrder(order);
            this.initializers.add(type, registration);
            if (this.log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                this.log.debug(
                        "Created " + type.getSimpleName() + " initializer for bean '"
                                + beanName + "'; order=" + order + ", resource="
                                + getResourceDescription(beanName, beanFactory));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line `List<Map.Entry<String, B>> beans = getOrderedBeansOfType(beanFactory, beanType,   this.seen);`, return list of 1 bean only (my servlet) although beanType is javax Servlet and I would expect DispatcherServlet to be there as well (I'm also using Spring MVC).

This results to an error in the following method (in class `ServletRegistrationBeanAdapter`):

```
@Override
    public RegistrationBean createRegistrationBean(String name, Servlet source,
            int totalNumberOfSourceBeans) {
        String url = (totalNumberOfSourceBeans == 1 ? "/" : "/" + name + "/");
        if (name.equals(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME)) {
            url = "/"; // always map the main dispatcherServlet to "/"
        }
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(source, url);
        bean.setMultipartConfig(this.multipartConfig);
        return bean;
    }
```

Since the beans list is of size 1, in the createRegistrationBean it hard codes the mapping to '/'.

This in turn causes they embedded jetty to fail starting as there are 2 mappings to '/' (DispatcherServlet and my PingServlet).

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: That is exactly what to expect, if you want to map it to a URL use a `ServletRegistrationBean` to specify the mapping and also to have it excluded from default processing (if you want the `PingServlet` to be handled by the `DispatcherServlet` for instance).

Comment: Thanks, I thought the bean name should work on itself. So it only works if my Servlet is the only one?

Comment: Correct, unless you specify a mapping through a `ServletRegistrationBean` or disable your servlet for registration, in the latter case the request would be handled by the `DispatcherServlet` which in turn dispatches it to your servlet based on the name of the bean and the URL that is going to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @M. Deinum This works:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean pingRegistration(PingServlet pingServlet) {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            pingServlet);
    registration.addUrlMappings("/probe/*");
    return registration;
}
```